# Best way to do Spring MVC without JSP?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat6

I wish to use Spring MVC to provide a REST web service. However, running through some books and tutorials, it looks like ModelAndView always returns a parsed JSP file. I guess I could make the JSP build my XML document, but is this the best way to go about things? I thought that perhaps a more structured XML building approach might be appropriate.

What are my options? Also, does anyone have any relevant tutorials?

Comment: You should look into the @RestController annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html) would probably help somewhat. It seems you are looking for a Marshalling View.

Alternatively, a JAX-RS implementation like Jersey or RESTeasy might suit you as well.

Answer (score 2):

The View part of ModelAndView does not have to represent a JSP.

See chapter 17 of the reference manual, for example in chapter 17.5 they describe how to set up a XSLT view (not what you need, but shows how different views are supported).

[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch17s05.html](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch17s05.html#view-xslt-subclassing)

Comment: +1. Neato. I wound up just using XOM to manually build XML, but I'll not this for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered integrating Spring with RESTlet library? [This page](http://www.bagdemir.com/2009/09/11/spring-mvc-restlet-integration-on-tomcat/) might be a good starting point...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options for marshaling java beans into either XML or JSON.  I use the spring-json package for rendering my model into JSON for my web service, and there are several choices if you want to render XML instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/).  Basically, XML is just text, and by using a templating system you could easily create your XML document that you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on http://www.jprovocateur.org . You can have a look on the online example and on the documentation on how the results are transformed in JSON/XML

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Using Angularjs is an awesome idea. It does require you to do spring restfull services. Here is an article about it: https://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/angular-js/migrating-spring-web-mvc-jsp-angularjs/